# Android dev no error inside eclipse but while running

Tags: android, eclipse

This is my code!! I am really really new to android dev and I would appreciate the help!! is anything wrong with it?

I am using eclipse and I am runnng it on a htc magic directly.

```
package fabian.hasan.droidx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DroidActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    int counter;
    Button add;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        counter = 0;
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPress);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNum);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter += 1;
                display.setText(counter);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Edit//

I changed a little bit of code and it worked: `display.setText("Count" + counter);`

Comment: You'll get more responses if you post the error that you're getting.

Comment: You should add your own answer to this question and mark your own answer as accepted if you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I assuming if you dig through Logcat you'll find a `ClassCastException`, because  `counter` is an int and setText(..) requires a String. Try `setText(Integer.toString(counter))`.